# What is the difference between "ちょっと" and "ちと"? Is one more polite than the other?

Tags: words, keigo

It seems like ちと　is more polite since I've seen more people use it. Is it true?

Comment: According to 大辞林, [ちょっと is derived from ちっと](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A1%E3%82%87%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8), which is in turn [derived from ちと](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A1%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8).  You can find a tiny bit more discussion on [this page](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/thsrs/14275/m0u/).  Another similar word is [ちょいと](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A1%E3%82%87%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8).

Comment: @OP No, it is not true, period.  It is MUCH more common to say ちょっと.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree that ちと is used more often than ちょっと. Rather than making you sound polite, I think using ちと would just make you sound odd for using such an uncommon word.

ちっと on the other hand is used reasonably often, especially in ちっとも.

If you'd like a more formal version of ちょっと, I think 少し would serve that purpose well in most situations.